# What does "cout << (long long) a+b+c-1" mean in C++14?

Tags: c++, variables, cout

What does putting a data type like `long` do after `cout` does, as demonstrated in the example below:

```
cout << (long long) a+b+c-1
```

a, b and c are three integer type variables.

Comment: it simply outputs a `long long`

Comment: It doesn't do anything after the `cout`.   It converts `a` to `long long`.   That affects how the summation `a + b + c - 1` is calculated - in particular what promotions, if any, are applied to `b`, `c`, and the literal `1` before adding/subtracting them.   The actual promotions applied - and the result of doing the summation - depend on the actual types of `b` and `c`.

Comment: You shouldn't use C style casts. Prefer a `static_cast<long long>`.

Answer (score 5):

It's not so much after the << as it is *before* the `a` in the expression `a+b+c-1`. It is casting the variable `a` to a `long long`.